# @Embedded Reference on Entity Giving java.lang.stackoverflow

Tags: mongodb, playframework, morphia

We have the following error when attempting to use an @Embedded object in Morphia on Play.

```
A java.lang.StackOverflowError has been caught, null Hide trace
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.init(LinkedHashMap.java:223)
at java.util.HashMap.(HashMap.java:210)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.(LinkedHashMap.java:181)
at org.bson.BasicBSONObject.(BasicBSONObject.java:39)
at com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.(BasicDBObject.java:42)
at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:435)
at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.Mapper.toDBObject(Mapper.java:430)
at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.writeCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:68)
at com.google.code.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.toDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:30)
```

This is caused by trying to save an instance of the following class:

```
@Entity
public class Profile extends Model
{
@Embedded
public class ObjectPermission
{
    public String type;
    public ArrayList<String> viewable;
    public ArrayList<String> editable;
}

public String _sfid;
public String _type;
@Embedded
public ArrayList<ObjectPermission> object;
}
```

We are attempting to save it in the following way:

```
@Test
public void TestFullProfileSave()
{
    Profile p = new Profile();
    p._sfid = "0123456789101213145";
    p._type = "entitlements";
    ObjectPermission objPerm = p.new ObjectPermission();
    objPerm.type = "Account";
    objPerm.viewable = new ArrayList<String>();
    objPerm.viewable.add("field1");
    objPerm.viewable.add("field2");
    objPerm.editable = new ArrayList<String>();
    objPerm.editable.add("field3");
    objPerm.editable.add("field4");
    p.object = new ArrayList<ObjectPermission>();
    p.object.add(objPerm);
    p.save();
}
```

I have a feeling it is the ArrayLists but don't know why hence my confusion. Thanks in advance.

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of morphia you will get a better error message about needing to declare the inner class as 'static'. That is the problem here.

> public **static** class ObjectPermission { ...

Answer (score -1):

As I remember you'd have to annotate the class with @Embeddable and only the reference as @Embedded.
But usually you'd do this with references to single objects. I don't think you can embedd whole collections. You should rather user @OneToMany to map the Objectpermission. That would cause a separate mapping table.

Comment: Seems to suggest here http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/EmbeddedAnnotation that you can do so though (bottom of page)

Comment: thx for the link, I have an (older) book that suggests `@Embeddable` I didn't know that `@Embedded` also works on classes.